# Error handling on react-native-fcm

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm integrating FCM on my react-native application using https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm.
The notification works but I got this error every time.

```
console.error: "Notification handler err", {"line":67974,"column":14,"sourceURL":"http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false"}
```

Environment:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.40.0

react-native-fcm: 6.1.0

I'm testing on Android ver 6.0.1 and the app is running in foreground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed old code Firebase initialisation code on index.js, and it caused the error.

```
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    storageBucket: ""
});
```

I removed it and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

For react-native fcm. See object **aps.alert**
[image]

```
FCM.on("FCMNotificationReceived", (notification) => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        if (notification && notification.aps) {
          const localNotification = {
            title: notification.aps.alert.title,
            body: notification.aps.alert.body,
            show_in_foreground: true,
          }
          FCM.presentLocalNotification(localNotification);
        }
      }
    });


FCM.on("FCMNotificationReceived", (notification) => {
// Also trigged when FCM.presentLocalNotification() and callback a notification without **aps** object;
// So the app crash, error
// Just check if (notification && notification.aps) and make localNotification object like above code
})
```